# Is it possible to maintain multiple clients in NanoHttpd?

Tags: websocket, nanohttpd

I am trying to build a simple server/client application where the NanoHttpd server communicates with the client using WebSockets.
The server replies back with the same text that the client sent.
Is it possible to broacast messages to all the clients connected?
Any links about Nanohttpd with multiple-clients connected would be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/PathikDevani/NanoHttpd-Demo

check my github project. here some example for multi user handle on websocket.

-------link is broken now

Comment: the link is broken